# Get the absolute file path from InputStream(ByteArrayInputStream) object

Tags: java, classpath, inputstream, bytearrayinputstream

I have the following piece of code:

```
class Train{
   static{
        InputStream inpStr = Train.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ABC.properties");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(inpStr);
   }
}
```

I want to know the absolute file path of this file ABC.properties, i.e from where inpStr  is reading it?
Through debugging, I realised the object assigned to inpStr is actually of `java.io.ByteArrayInputStream`. But I unable to find a way to get the abolute file path. Please help

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get resource, not resourceAsStream:

```java
URL resource = Train.class.getClassLoader().getResource("ABC.properties");
```

Then you get the path

```java
Path path = Paths.get(resource.toURI());
```

And finally you can display the absolutePath

```java
System.out.println(path.toAbsolutePath().toString());
```